# Right and Wrong answer functions in java for radiobuttons, checkboxes, etc

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext, radio-button

Does anyone have an example of a radiobutton, checkbox, and edittext questions being answered and showing which are the correct and which are the wrong answers? Also how can I get the functions for the score for each right answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to implement a question and answer functionality

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972962/2610808